# Memory Exception on copying large size PDF File Using iText 7 C# (Version 7.1.12)

Tags: .net, itext, itext7

I am trying to do some manipulation on existing document (Size of 3 GB).
I find no problem in reading the document with PdfReader.
I am getting memory exception on while copying exsting document pages to new document.
Please find the code snippet  i have created

```
string inputFile = CommonHelper.GetPdfFilePath("MergeRootAttributesOntoPage.pdf");
            string outputFile = CommonHelper.GetOutputPdfFile("MergeRootAttributesOntoPage_iText7");
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(
                                                new RandomAccessSourceFactory().SetForceRead(false).CreateBestSource(inputFile),
                                                new ReaderProperties()
                                                    );
            PdfDocumentWrapper sourceDocument = new PdfDocumentWrapper(pdfReader, true);
            PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(outputFile).SetSmartMode(true);
            PdfDocumentWrapper destinationDocument = new PdfDocumentWrapper(pdfWriter);
            destinationDocument.InitializeOutlines();

            sourceDocument.CopyPagesTo(1, sourceDocument.GetNumberOfPages(),destinationDocument);
            sourceDocument.Close();
            destinationDocument.Close();
```

Copy scenario with PDf Merge object :

```
 string inputFile = CommonHelper.GetPdfFilePath("MergeRootAttributesOntoPage.pdf");
            string outputFile = CommonHelper.GetOutputPdfFile("MergeRootAttributesOntoPage_iText7");
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(
                                                new RandomAccessSourceFactory().SetForceRead(false).CreateBestSource(inputFile),
                                                new ReaderProperties()
                                                );
            PdfDocumentWrapper sourceDocument = new PdfDocumentWrapper(pdfReader, true);
            PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(outputFile).SetSmartMode(true);
            PdfDocumentWrapper destinationDocument = new PdfDocumentWrapper(pdfWriter);
            PdfMerger resultDocument = new PdfMerger(destinationDocument).SetCloseSourceDocuments(true);
            resultDocument.Merge(sourceDocument, 1, sourceDocument.GetNumberOfPages()).Close();
            resultDocument.Close();
```

Copy pages one by one

```
 string inputFile = CommonHelper.GetPdfFilePath("MergeRootAttributesOntoPage.pdf");
            string outputFile = CommonHelper.GetOutputPdfFile("MergeRootAttributesOntoPage_iText7");
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(
                                                new RandomAccessSourceFactory().SetForceRead(false).CreateBestSource(inputFile),
                                                new ReaderProperties()
                                                );
            PdfDocumentWrapper sourceDocument = new PdfDocumentWrapper(pdfReader, true);
            PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(outputFile).SetSmartMode(true);
            PdfDocumentWrapper destinationDocument = new PdfDocumentWrapper(pdfWriter);
            destinationDocument.SetCloseWriter(false);
            destinationDocument.InitializeOutlines();
            PdfPageFormCopier pdfPageFormCopier = new PdfPageFormCopier();

            for (int i = 1; i <= sourceDocument.GetNumberOfPages(); ++i)
            {
               destinationDocument.AddPage(sourceDocument.GetPage(i).CopyTo(destinationDocument, pdfPageFormCopier));
            }
```

All above methods ended with memory exception on copying objects
Any solution is warm welcome

Comment: How much memory is consumed by the code? Have you tried increasing memory size?

Comment: Nearly 91 % of the cpu memory is utilized

Comment: 271265792 values obtained by using following code
 ```
 Process currentProc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
 long memoryUsed = currentProc.PrivateMemorySize64;
 ```

Comment: That's less than 270 MB, correct? It does not look like high memory consumption in a modern environment